# Running test from script in 2022 with MT5

Tags: automated-tests, mql5, metatrader5

I've been working on a bash script to run with MSYS on windows, that should be able to launch a test and get me the report in html report. But all I've managed to do was launch the terminal without anything configured.

using a config file similar to:

```
 ; start strategy tester
  TestExpert=<full path to .ex5 file>
  TestExpertParameters=<full path to .set file>
  TestSymbol=WDOV22
  TestPeriod=H1
  TestModel=2
  TestSpread=0
  TestOptimization=false
  TestDateEnable=true
  TestFromDate=2022.01.01
  TestToDate=2022.06.06
  TestReport=<full path to non existing file without extension>
  TestReplaceReport=true
  TestShutdownTerminal=true
```

If I go to a PowerShell window and run:

```
.\terminal64.exe "<fullpath to config file>"
```

or:

```
.\terminal64.exe /config:"<fullpath to config file>"
```

or:

```
.\terminal64.exe /portable /config:"<fullpath to config file>"
```

And other variations, all that happens is that MetaTrader5 opens, no test is executed, the configuration on the tester is unchanged and so on.

Questions:

1 - Anyone managed to do something similar? All answers in this forum seem really outdated and the documentation is quite confusing.

2 - Is there some specific encoding required for the .ini file? Does it need to be ASCII or does UTF-8 suffices?

3 - Does the /portable flag even work? Is it necessary?

4 - Am I doing something absurdly wrong? Doesn't MT5 give some hint somehow of what I could be doing wrong?

5 - The journal says cloud servers are off, but I am trying to test locally anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have checked your Journal/Log? As an ini-file I used one existing generated by MT5 and customized it by myself.

I just put my batch-setup together in a repo, you can find it in my github-account: [FuscaSoftware MT5BatchSetup](https://github.com/FuscaSoftware/MT5BatchSetup)
I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually reports are excel so I am not sure there but for guidance this is my bat file, you can modify it as required or whatever you want to do.

However it is quite advanced, you will only need one ini file per EA that you want to test and the bat file code modifies the pair with powershell and also adjusts the report name via powershell before starting MT5 tester.  This is ideal for me as I want to run many pairs rather than just one pair over and over, could be useful so here it is.

For the ini file the following link is quite useful. [enter link description here](https://github.com/FuscaSoftware/MT5BatchSetup)

```html
@echo off
echo Startscript to start MT5 optimization/backtester automated.

set "iniFile=D:\MT5Tester2\YOUR EA NAME HERE.ini"

:: Define the list of currency pairs to loop over
set "pairs=AUDUSD EURJPY EURUSD GBPJPY GBPUSD NZDUSD USDCAD USDCHF USDJPY"

:: Loop over each currency pair
for %%p in (%pairs%) do (
    
    :: Set the currency pair in the ini file
    powershell -Command "(Get-Content \"%iniFile%\") -replace 'Symbol=.*', 'Symbol=%%p' | Set-Content \"%iniFile%\""
    
    :: Set the report path in the ini file
    powershell -Command "(Get-Content \"%iniFile%\") -replace 'Report=.*', 'Report=reports\YOUR EA NAME HERE %%p' | Set-Content \"%iniFile%\""
    
    :: Run the tests 5 times for the current currency pair
    for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do (
        echo Pair: %%p, Iteration: %%i
        echo %date% - %time%
        D:\MT5Tester2\terminal64.exe /portable /config:"%iniFile%"
        echo %date% - %time%
    )
)

echo "Finished!"
PAUSE
```